# How to maintain other label's position?

Tags: swift, snapkit

I'm building an app that can add UILabel(can move with gesture) on UIView.

First, Add a label and move it to another position.
Second, Add another label.
Then makeConstraints have an effect on first label.

I wanna maintain first label's position
How can I do?

```
@IBAction func touchAddText(_ sender: Any) {
    logp("touchAddText")
    let newLabel = UILabel()
    newLabel.text = "Text"
    newLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newLabel.tag = self.labelList.count + 1
    newLabel.addGestureRecognizer(self.setGesture())
    self.labelList.append(newLabel)
    self.containerMain.addSubview(newLabel)
    newLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.center.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Solved.
Don't activate constraints, change label's center with CGPoint.

```
newLabel.sizeToFit()
newLabel.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: self.containerMain.bounds.midY)
```